# OpenCv 3.4....cv2.StereoCalibrate()...Required argument distcoeff1 (pos5) not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, stereo-3d

we are trying to stereo calibrate and using the following code to complete the task.

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import glob

    # termination criteria
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    # prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
    objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

    # Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
    objpoints = {} # 3d point in real world space
    imgpoints = {} # 2d points in image plane.

    # calibrate stereo
    for side in ['Left', 'Right']:
    counter = 0
    images = glob.glob('E:\Calibration\%s*.jpg' %side)
objpoints[side] = [];
imgpoints[side] = [];
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6),None)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints[side].append(objp)

        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints[side].append(corners)
        counter += 1

assert counter == len(images), "missed chessboard!!"


stereocalib_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 100, 1e-5)
stereocalib_flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO | cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST |   cv2.CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH | cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3 | 
cv2.CALIB_FIX_K4 | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K5
retval,cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = 
cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpoints['Left'], imgpoints['Left'], imgpoints['Right'], (640, 480), criteria = stereocalib_criteria, flags = stereocalib_flags)`
```

we are facing the following error in using cv2.stereoCalibrate

Error getting:

> File "C:\Users\Shehroz
>   Iqbal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Calib_Stereo_Try2.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       retval,cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpoints['Left'], imgpoints['Left'],
>   imgpoints['Right'], (640, 480), criteria = stereocalib_criteria, flags
>   = stereocalib_flags) TypeError: Required argument 'distCoeffs1' (pos 5) not foundTraceback (most recent call last):

Comment: You're not giving the `stereoCalibrate` function the right data. If you read the error it's telling you that the "Required argument 'distCoeffs1' (pos 5)" is "not found". You might want to [read the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate) for that function to try and work out how it wants the data passed to it.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis I did try it but for that it documentation says that distcoeff should be inside arguments so I first calibrated the cameras individually and used the respective distcoeff in the input arguments but now it is giving an other error                                                   error: (-215) nimages > 0 && nimages == (int)imagePoints1.total() && (!imgPtMat2 || nimages == (int)imagePoints2.total()) in function cv::collectCalibrationData