# cv2.stereoCalibrate() function - TypeError: stereoCalibrate() missing required argument

Tags: python, opencv

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191221/opencv-3-4-cv2-stereocalibrate-required-argument-distcoeff1-pos5-not-fo), but it's not been answered: 
My code portion is as follows:

```
(ret, mat1,dist1,mat2,dist2, R, T, E, F) = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
            objpoints1,
            imgpoints1,
            imgpoints2,
            imgsize1, criteria=None, flags=None)
```

And I get the following error:

> TypeError: stereoCalibrate() missing required argument 'distCoeffs1' (pos 5)

According to the documentation: [Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction: cv2.stereoCalibrate()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#double%20stereoCalibrate(InputArrayOfArrays%20objectPoints,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints1,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints2,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20OutputArray%20R,%20OutputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20E,%20OutputArray%20F,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20flags)), the parameters of "cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2" are input/outputs and it's not needed to be pass them into the function call.

See the quotation below:

> If any of CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS , CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO , CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC , or CV_CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH are specified, some or all of the matrix components must be initialized. See the flags description for details.

I have also seen some applications where people omitted those parameters and let the function estimate them. I cannot see what is different in my code in comparison to them and/or how can I trigger the function not to check those parameters and work as stated in the documentation and in a few applications that are available online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you are referring to is likely for much older version than you are actually using. For [latest OpenCV release (4.2.0)](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5) the  function signature is:

> retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F    =   cv.stereoCalibrate( objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, imageSize[, R[, T[, E[, F[, flags[, criteria]]]]]]

where 5th argument is `distCoeffs1`, which is also reported in the error message.

You need to pass all the required arguments (objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, imageSize) to `stereoCalibrate()`.